# Filtering posts by tag

Tags: filter, yaml, jekyll, octopress

I have a new Jekyll/Octopress site.

I made some customizations: I added a category_list_tag.rb file (from Dan Watson) to the plugins folder to create categories, and I then duplicated the category_generator.rb and the category_list_tag.rb to create a tag_generator.rb and tag_list_tag.rb.

I now have multiple ways to 'group' posts together, and in the sidebar, this all works well.

At the bottom of each post, I would now like to show a list of posts that have the same tag(s) as the post in question.

I am still a newbie and learning all of this, and have managed to hack the following together:

In the YAML Front Matter, I have the following:

```
---
title: "Preface"
date: 2012-09-02 18:30
layout: post

categories:
- Section 1

tags:
- Author
- About
- Publisher
---
```

And in an include file, I have the following to go at the bottom of each post:

```
<ul class="inline">
  {% for tag in site.tags %} 
    <li><a href="{{ url_root }}#{{ tag[0] }}-ref">{{ tag[0] }} <span>({{ tag[1].size }})</span></a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<ul class="posts inline">
  {% for tag in site.tags %}
  <h5 id="{{ tag[0] }}-ref">{{ tag[0] }}</h5>

  {% for post in tag[1] %}
    <li><a href="{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}

  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This of course, shows ALL the posts listed by ALL the tags, which is nice, but not what I want.

How do I rewrite this so ONLY the posts with the SAME tag(s) as the post I am on, are listed at the end of the post?

This is really troubling me and I can't seem to think it through properly.

UPDATE: I have solved part of the problem with the following changes to the above code snippet:

```
{% for tag in page.tags %}
<h5 id="{{ tag }}-ref">{{ tag }}</h5>
  {% for post in site.posts reversed %}
  <li><a href="{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

However it's not quite right... the tag heading lists the tags associated with each post, which is what I want, but under each tag heading, ALL posts are listed, rather than just those posts associated with that tag... hmmm.

Thanks in advance if you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, you could try something along these lines:

```
{% for tag in page.tags %}
  <h5 id="{{ tag }}-ref">{{ tag }}</h5>

  {% for post in site.posts reversed %}

    {% if post.tags contains tag %}
      <li><a href="{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

It'll verify if the tag exists in a post's tags array. If it does, it'll print the `<li>...</li>` part.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Thank You @agarie! The code works beautifully. I'm not sure I fully understand the logic but I will explore that more fully in the morning. Cheers.